# Error Bound Trapezoidal Rule problem

Tags: integration

Hello all haven't asked a lot of questions on here so I hope this isn't frowned upon if I ask it wrong.

I want to follow the logic of this Trapezoidal Rule problem here is the problem:

[http://imgur.com/a/oj1qZ](https://imgur.com/a/oj1qZ)

I labeled the area of confusion. Why is an inequality set up? why 8/(3n^2) in between? How does 8/(3n^2) ≤ 1/9 go from that to 3n^2/8 ≥ 9? and then to n^{2} ≥ 24 and finally how is it all combined to form: 4 ≤ sqrt(24) ≤ 5, where does n = 5 come from? I am confused by a lot this, mainly the algebra. Am fine up till plugging in K_t but the rest I am not understanding.

Thank you

Comment: Thank you!
So 'n' represents an integer of the absolute worst case. Still ify on why 5 of all numbers was chosen. Could you elaborate on that process?

Comment: Oh wow it's because n ≥ √(24) so we know that n is the larger there and that we have a lower bound already established as 4 so then we just crunch those together as 4 ≤ √(24) ≤ n
and then we simply bump up 24 to get to a number BIGGER than itself and that's the upper bound √(25) works nicely out to be 5 so that missing n = 5
Sorry put that in hillbilly terms.